# Control.Add changes the controls location

Tags: c#, winforms

This is going to be difficult to explain.

Here's how my custom control is working:

1. I made a custom listview containing a ContainerControl and a VScrollBar
2. Items in the listview get added to the ContainerControl, on a scroll move, the items get repositioned in the ContainerControl.

That's the basic idea of a custom listview.

Now: Each ListviewItem has a height of 111 & works like a charm.
Until I add exactly 295 items, the items after those get some weird looking things.

Each ListviewItem contains something like a picturebox, progressbar, labels, some buttons & some custom painting in the Paint event.

Now everything on the ListviewItems that gets painted (in the Paint event) is positioned correctly. However, some (!) of the controls that are being added with Controls.Add() are not, they seem to get a negative Y value.

When I set a breakpoint after the SomeControl.Location = new Point(x, y), the control does have the correct value, but after I add the control to the ListviewItem with Controls.Add(), the Y value is negative.
The weirdest part is that some controls do not get this, this might be a way to the solution of this problem.

I really hope you can understand what I'm trying to figure out, please ask me if you don't understand something.

EDIT: This is WinForms.
Can't show a lot of code as it's just Control.Location = x; and Controls.Add(c);

Comment: Code, code and more code.  Show the code, point to the place where it is going wrong, someone will tell you the bug.

Comment: 111 x 295 = 32745 and 296th control causes an overflow i guess. So it has a negative value. try to reduce the heights if possible.

Comment: unfortunately, that's not possible. The number of items depends on the user & the height being 111 has a reason. Can I avoid that overflow anyhow, because it's still drawing strings & adding some of the controls ?

Comment: just for understanding you may reduce the heights for example to 100px then run again. If weird things start later this shows I am right. just for experiment

Comment: You are right, it seems to add more items properly. Still how is it adding some of the controls & some not. Although I wouldn't know what could have overflown except for the .Top value of a single ListviewItem. As those controls' location are relative to the ListviewItem & not to the full Listview

Comment: I think you have to change your approach. I do not have any idea what you are trying but maybe you can use tabView control instead of a flowing layout. Then you would have more spaces.

Comment: The program lists downloads in the listview and each item contains information for a download, a tabview is a bit weird here. How can a small number like 32000 cause an overflow though ? Why isn't it throwing errors then? Thanks for your help by the way

Comment: I kind of fixed it by changing the control's Location after Control.Add(), although it's a noob way in my opinion, I don't know any other way.